# Mahout recommendation in implicit feedback situation

Tags: java, mahout-recommender

I'm working with the Mahout framework in order to get recommendations in implicit feedback context using the well-known movielens dataset (ml-100k) that I have binarized considering 1 all the ratings equal to four or five, zero all the other.
In this dataset there are five split, each of which divided in test set and training set
as usually.

In the recommendation process I train the recommender using a simple GenericBooleanPrefUserBasedRecommender and the TanimotoCoefficientSimilarity as described in these lines of code:

```
    DataModel trainModel = new FileDataModel(new File(String.valueOf(Main.class.getResource("/binarized/u1.base").getFile())));
    DataModel testModel = new FileDataModel(new File(String.valueOf(Main.class.getResource("/binarized/u1.test").getFile())));
    UserSimilarity similarity = new TanimotoCoefficientSimilarity(trainModel);
    UserNeighborhood neighborhood = new NearestNUserNeighborhood(35, similarity, trainModel);

    GenericBooleanPrefUserBasedRecommender userBased = new GenericBooleanPrefUserBasedRecommender(trainModel, neighborhood, similarity);

    long firstUser = testModel.getUserIDs().nextLong(); // get the first user

    // try to recommender items for the first user
    for(LongPrimitiveIterator iterItem = testModel.getItemIDsFromUser(firstUser).iterator(); iterItem.hasNext(); ) {
        long currItem = iterItem.nextLong();
        // estimates preference for the current item for the first user
        System.out.println("Estimated preference for item " + currItem + " is " + userBased.estimatePreference(firstUser, currItem));

    }
```

When I execute this code, the result is a list of 0.0 or 1.0 which are not useful in the context of top-n recommendation in implicit feedback context. Simply because I have to obtain, for each item, an estimated rate which stays in the range [0, 1] in order to rank the list in decreasing order and construct the top-n recommendation appropriately.

So what's the problem with this code? Have I missed something or something was incorrect?
Or maybe is the Mahout framework that doesn't provide a proper way of using binary feedback?

Thank you in advance,

Alessandro Suglia

Answer (score 0):

If you want recommendations you are calling the wrong function. You have to call recommend

```
List<RecommendedItem> items = userBased.recommend(firstUser, 10);
for(RecommendedItem item : items) {
    System.out.println(item.getItemID()+" Estimated preference: "+item.getValue());
}
```

More information can be found at the javadocs:
https://builds.apache.org/job/mahout-quality/javadoc/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/recommender/Recommender.html

An extensive code example can be found here:

https://github.com/ManuelB/facebook-recommender-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/de/apaxo/bedcon/FacebookRecommender.java

Comment: But this method doesn't grant to me to estimate preference for items that aren't in the training set which is exactly what I need to do because I use another tool in order to evaluate my system. Thank you for your answer

Comment: If you want to evaluate the performance of your recommender take a look into: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/trunk/mrlegacy/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/impl/eval/GenericRecommenderIRStatsEvaluator.java and http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/trunk/mrlegacy/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/impl/eval/RMSRecommenderEvaluator.java Further the test cases contain good examples: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/trunk/mrlegacy/src/test/java/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/impl/eval/GenericRecommenderIRStatsEvaluatorImplTest.java

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to evaluation the recommender offline and you are using the in-memory item or user based recommender then Mahout has an evaluation framework for this. It will split the data into training and test automatically and randomly. It trains on the training set and run an evaluation on the test set giving back several metrics.

Check out the "Evaluation" section at the bottom of the wiki page here:
https://mahout.apache.org/users/recommender/userbased-5-minutes.html

Each run of this will yield slightly different results due to the random hold out set.

I would caution about doing this across different recommender algorithms since the test is only checking one against itself. To compare two algorithms or implementations is more complicated. Be sure to use exactly the same data, training and test splits, and even then the results are questionable until you do A/B user testing.

**Update:**
offline you said you are using a particular evaluation system and can't use Mahout's--no matter. Here is how it's done:

You can remove some data from the dataset. So remove certain preferences. Then train and obtain recommendations for the user’s who had some data withheld. The test data has not been used to train and get recs so you then compare what users’ actually preferred to the prediction made by the recommender. If all of them match you have 100% precision. Note that you are comparing recommendations to actual but held-out preferences.

If you are using some special tools you may be doing this to compare algorithms, which is not an exact thing at all, no matter what the Netflix prize may have led us to believe. If you are using offline tests to tune a specific recommender you may have better luck with the results.

In one installation we had real data and split it into test and training by date. 90% of older data was used to train, the most recent 10% was used to test. This would mimic the way data comes in. We compared the recommendations from the training data against the actual preferences in the help-out data and used MAP@some-number-of-recs as the score. This allows you to measure ranking, where RMSE does not. The Map score led us to several useful conclusions about tuning that were data dependent.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval#Mean_average_precision

Comment: I simply need a way to get for a specific user "U1" a specific estimated preference for the item "i4", which in my case, should be a value between 0 and 1, and not only 0 or 1, as the Mahout estimatePreference() returns.
Is it incorrect?

Comment: no, you compare the .recommend(userId) against the held-out preferences for that user. If your preferences are 1 or 0 then you would see if recommendations (itemIds) include the items that the user actually preferred with a 1 in the held-out data. Check the MAP description about how to make the calculation. If your eval tool does this some other way it is still likely comparing the prediction (recommendations) to the actual held-out preferences for a single user. Then it averages that number over all users.